# NoneType object has no attribute groups?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

i m trying to split the image path and text from the `list` using regex in python

the code is working fine which is given below

```
pattern = r'^(?:(.*?) )?(https?:\/\/\S+) (.*)$|^(?:(.*?) )?(SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____\S+) ?(.*)$'
strings = [
           "ulr was this SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4- 
           eb100c432091.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END and click here to see details",
           "Automation Details",
           "SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END",
           "SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END",
           "Automation Details Hello",
           "SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END",
        ]
       for string in strings:
            parts = re.search(pattern, string)
            non_null_groups = list(filter(None.__ne__, parts.groups()))
            print(non_null_groups)
```

but it's give me error on string elements in `list`

Error is on `Automation Details` & `Automation Details Hello`

`Error is AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute groups`

How to get rid of this from Error Any Help would be Appreciated & thanks in Advance

Comment: Before assigning any value to `non_null_groups`, check `if parts:`

Comment: thanks man now its working error has gone now